# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open_openwork'

Tags: python, django, excel

I want to import an EXCEL file ,but there is some wrong with the codes.Help!

```
import xlrd

fname = "D:/pdf-ex/exc.xls"
bk = xlrd.open_openwork("fname","rb")
shxrange = range(bk.nsheets)
sh = bk.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
nrows = sh.nrows
ncols = sh.ncols
print "nrows %d, ncols %d" % (nrows,ncols)

cell_value = sh.cell_value(1,1)
print cell_value

row_list = []
for i in range(1,nrows):
    row_data = sh.row_values(i)
    row_list.append(row_data)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting a syntax error or a run time error or is the result incorrect?

Comment: I am sorry. Just now , I give the wrong codes. In fact, ".open_openwork" should be ".open_workbook".

Comment: @wangling: Yes, as I suggested. Delete or accept then ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is because `xlrd` module does not have `open_openwork()` function in it.

The function you may be looking for is [`open_workbook()`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#__init__.open_workbook-function):

> `open_workbook(...)` - Open a spreadsheet file for data extraction.

Plus there is nothing about the mode in the docs - by providing second argument you set the log file (opened file object to which messages will be read).

So instead of:

```
bk = xlrd.open_openwork("fname","rb")
```

do:

```
bk = xlrd.open_workbook("fname")
```

Comment: I mend it. However,there some new wrong.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pdf-ex\test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    bk = xlrd.open_workbook(fp)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 366, in open_workbook
    formatting_info=formatting_info,
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 725, in __init__
    f = open(filename, open_mode)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: @wangling: That tells me not much. Post your code somewhere (ideone.com? codepad.com? pastebin.com?) and tell me which line is no. 3 in this file.

Comment: import xlrd 
import sys 
fname = "D:/pdf-ex/exc.xlsx" 
bk = xlrd.open_openwork("fname") 
shxrange = range(bk.nsheets) 
sh = bk.sheet_by_name("Sheet1") 
nrows = sh.nrows 
ncols = sh.ncols 
print "nrows %d, ncols %d" % (nrows,ncols) 
 
cell_value = sh.cell_value(1,1) 
print cell_value 
 
row_list = [] 
for i in range(1,nrows): 
    row_data = sh.row_values(i) 
    row_list.append(row_data)