# How to read from an excel sheet using pythons xlrd module

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I have the following code. What am I trying to do is screenscrape a website and then write the data to an excel worksheet. I can't read the existing data from excel file.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import os  
links= open('links.txt', encoding='utf-8')
#excel workbook
if os.path.isfile('./TestSheet.xls'):
    rbook=xlrd.open_workbook('TestSheet.xls',formatting_info=True)
    book=copy(rbook)
else:
    book = xlwt.Workbook()

try:
    book.add_sheet("wayanad")
except:
    print("sheet exists")
    sheet=book.get_sheet(1)

for line in links:
    print("Currently Scanning\n","\n=================\n",line.rstrip())
    url=str(line.rstrip())    
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    #print(soup.prettify())
    title=soup.find('h1').get_text()    
    data=[]
    for i in soup.find_all('p'):
       data.append(i.get_text())
    quick_descr=data[1].strip()
    category=data[2].strip()
    tags=data[3].strip()
    owner=data[4].strip()
    website=data[6].strip()
    full_description=data[7]
    address=re.sub('\s+', ' ', soup.find('h3').get_text()).strip()
    city=soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "addressRegion"}).get_text().strip()
    postcode=soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "postalCode"}).get_text().strip()
    phone=[]
    result=soup.findAll('h4')
    for h in result:
        if h.has_attr('itemprop'):
            phone.append(re.sub("\D", "", h.get_text()))

    #writing data to excel
    row=sheet.last_used_row
    column_count=sheet.ncols()    
    book.save("Testsheet.xls")
    time.sleep(2)
```

**The code explained**

- I have a links file there are many links line by line. So pick a line(URL) and go that URL and scrape the data.
- Open an excel workbook and switch to a sheet for writing data.
- append the data to excel sheet.->>

Screenshot of execl sheet structure
[image]

Currently the list is empty. But i want to continue from the last row. 
I coudn't read data from the cell. The [documentation says](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) there is `sheet.ncols` is avilable to count the columns. But it throws an error

```
>>>column_count=sheet.ncols()
>>>AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'ncols'
```

What i wanted is a way to count rows and columns, and read the data from cell. Many turials are old. Now i am using python 3.4. I've already gone through this links and many other. But no luck

[Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747385/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-open-openwork)

[Stackoverdlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088864/python-open-existing-excel-file-and-count-rows-in-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you are looking for ? Going through all col.?

```
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook

num_cols = xl_sheet.ncols
for row_idx in range(0, xl_sheet.nrows):
```

Comment: As you can see in the code i have a worksheet called `sheet`. But `sheet.nrows` throws error which is sheet does not have this property.`>>> sheet.nrows
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#125>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet.nrows
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'nrows'
>>> `

Comment: it worked perfectly last time for me like this:   `xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r".xlsx")`
    `sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()`
    `xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])`
    `num_cols = xl_sheet.ncols`
    `for row_idx in range(0, xl_sheet.nrows):`

Comment: Yep Even though your answer wasn't correct your comment gave me the idea. If I wanted to read data from a sheet. The sheet needs to be an `xlrd` object but in my case (the `sheet` object) is an `xlwt` Object. Thanks

Comment: great that it helped :)